# use while loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, subplot

let us consider following code

```
clear all;
 B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
% n=input('enter the number  from 1 to 16 for  windows  in periodogram :');
 fs=input('enter sampling frequency  fs :');
 while  1
     n=input('enter the number  from 1 to 16 for  windows  in periodogram :');
 switch n
     case 1
         disp('this is  hann window ');
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,hann(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,1);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 2
         disp('this is hamming window ');
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,hamming(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,2);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 3
         disp('this is kaiser window ');
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,kaiser(length(B),2.5),length(B),fs);
        subplot(4,4,3);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 4
         disp('this is barlett window ');
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,bartlett(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,4);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 5
         disp('this is bohmanwin window ');
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,bohmanwin(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,5);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 6
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,rectwin(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,6);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 7
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,triang(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,7);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 8
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,gausswin(length(B),2.5),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,8);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 9
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,flattopwin(length(B),'periodic'),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,9);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 10
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,gausswin(length(B),2.5),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,10);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 11
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,tukeywin(length(B),0.5),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,11);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 12 
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,taylorwin(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,12);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 13
        [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,barthannwin(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,13);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
          case 14 
          [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,parzenwin(length(B)),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,14);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
     case 15
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,nuttalwin(length(B),'periodic'),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,15);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on

     case 16 
         [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,nuttalwin(length(B),'periodic'),length(B),fs);
         subplot(4,4,15);
         plot(f,pxx);
         hold on
         otherwise
        warning('Unexpected number typed. No windows is used ');
 end
                 break;
 end
```

my  goal is that  using loop i want to enter at each step some number from 1 to 16 and  make subpplot of  power spectral density using periodogram with several different  windows,but when i run,it only shows me  plotting only one times,that means for example if i enter number 1,it shows me hann window and then stop,how can i make loop  through each step and at the same time to keep previously plotted graph?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `break` call.  The whole point of `break` is to exit early out of a loop.  Since you don't want to exit early, don't call `break`.

Comment: thanks for help,what about size?how can i enlarge size of each window?